# How do I prevent web parts from disappearing when copying a web part page to a new tenancy (Sharepoint 2013 Online)

Tags: 2013, web-part, sharepoint-online, content-migration

I am needing to copy multiple pages from a Sharepoint online tenancy (Let's call it 'Tenancy A') to Sharepoint tenancies 'B', 'C', 'D' etc..

This works without issue when copying pages that contain just HTML in the body (as long as the target tenancies have the correct page layouts installed).

What is happening however, is that ALL pages that contain web parts are displaying blank when copied and viewed on the second tenancies.

When editing the page on the secondary tenancies it shows that there are no web parts at all present, so they seem to be "dropping off" when being copied over. These are not custom web parts either, just the standard Content Editor Web Part and Media Web Part.

How can I copy these web part pages over to the new tenancies without having to manually re-add in all the web parts?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the WebPartId and other Id attributes for the Web Parts when you copy them to other tenancies.. Web Parts and Pages are referenced with Web Part Ids and once you copy the Web Part to other tenancy the reference is updated for the new page and thus no longer exists in the source.

So before pasting, copy it into a Notepad file and change all the Id attributes (you can generate new Guids using [GUID Generator](http://www.guidgenerator.com/online-guid-generator.aspx)

I hope this helps